# Emacs 26.3: jerky scroll

Tags: emacs

Emac's scrolling is quite jerky and unpredictable.  Weirdly, as you scroll, the top line nearly never is a line with no characters--but is very very rarely.  My best guess is that emacs's vertical scrollbar is perhaps not considering the number of lines in the file but the number of characters, or something?  Then once it finds the character it wants to have on the top line it backtracks to find the beginning of that character?

Any way to simply have this give every line an equal share of the scrollbar scroll region?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmoothScrolling) any use to you?

Comment: wow, I'm sure something there will work!  In fact I'd like to hear any reason to keep the current functionality; I'd consider it to simply be a bug..  Ergonomically speaking it's simply incorrect to have one program out of so many scroll differently.  I like coming up with my own ways of doing things but for ergonomic matters like this its often best to stick with the status quo: QWERTY keyboard etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to my `~/.emacs` file.

The first three adjust appearance while using the scroll bar.  Just `scroll-conservatively` may be enough in most cases but I see edge cases where the other two seem to help.  I don't have a full explanation and would like to know more if anyone has an idea.

The next two affect the mouse's scroll wheel.  Specifically, the `mouse-wheel-scroll-amount` setting means move 2 lines per wheel click normally, 10 lines if shift is being held down. or entire page (what `nil` means in this use) (the number of lines on the screen) if control is being held down.  `mouse-wheel-progressive-speed` prevents scroll from getting faster and faster as you do more of it.

```
(setq scroll-step 1)
(setq scroll-conservatively 10000)
(setq auto-window-vscroll nil)

(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(2 ((shift) . 10) ((control) . nil)))
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
```